# Get 3 data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I am wondering how to get 3 data out from database with this example:

```
    $query->select(array('Name','Pos1','Pos2'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__regions'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('Name').'='.$_REQUEST['name']);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $name = $db->loadResult();
    $pos1 = $db->loadResult();
    $pos2 = $db->loadResult();
```

I want to have data $name , $pos1 and $pos2. Or should i make
code for each value i need?
Thanks

Comment: `where($db->quoteName('Name').'='.$_REQUEST['name'].' LIMIT 3');`

Comment: 3 columns or 3 rows?

Comment: i want to get $name, $pos1 and $pos2.

Comment: What is the db table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change from

```
$query->select(array('Name','Pos1','Pos2'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__regions'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('Name').'='.$_REQUEST['name']);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $name = $db->loadResult();
    $pos1 = $db->loadResult();
    $pos2 = $db->loadResult();
```

to

```
$query->select('Name','Pos1','Pos2')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__regions'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('Name').'='.$_REQUEST['name']);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($results as $row) :
        $name =  $row->Name;
        $pos1 = $row->Pos1;
        $pos2 =  $row->Pos2;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: @Sked: answer provided

Comment: Thank you this code works great. You solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome :) if you think code is working then accept answer